# How do you show and hide multiple different elements on different clicks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, show-hide

I used the `onClick` function on each triggering element to make it show/hide multiple element IDs on click. The show/hide elements are hidden by default using the CSS display property (except for the first 3 main elements). The onClick event will change the display property of multiple elements to make some visible and some not. As the list of triggering elements and show/hide elements is growing, the script will become very inefficient and repetitive. How else can I achieve the following without using a lot of duplicate javascript pieces? The snippet below is a very simplified version of the script.

```js
function trigger1(){
  document.getElementById('trigger1').style.display ='none';
  document.getElementById('trigger2').style.display ='none';
  document.getElementById('trigger3').style.display ='none';
  document.getElementById('element1').style.display ='block';
  document.getElementById('element2').style.display ='block';
  document.getElementById('element3').style.display ='block';
  document.getElementById('element4').style.display ='none';
  document.getElementById('element5').style.display ='none';
  document.getElementById('subelement1').style.display ='none';
  document.getElementById('subelement2').style.display ='none';
  document.getElementById('subelement3').style.display ='none';
}
function trigger2(){
  document.getElementById('trigger1').style.display ='none';
  document.getElementById('trigger2').style.display ='none';
  document.getElementById('trigger3').style.display ='none';
  document.getElementById('element1').style.display ='none';
  document.getElementById('element2').style.display ='none';
  document.getElementById('element3').style.display ='none';
  document.getElementById('element4').style.display ='block';
  document.getElementById('element5').style.display ='block';
  document.getElementById('subelement1').style.display ='none';
  document.getElementById('subelement2').style.display ='none';
  document.getElementById('subelement3').style.display ='none';
}
function trigger3(){
  document.getElementById('trigger1').style.display ='none';
  document.getElementById('trigger2').style.display ='none';
  document.getElementById('trigger3').style.display ='none';
  document.getElementById('element1').style.display ='block';
  document.getElementById('element2').style.display ='none';
  document.getElementById('element3').style.display ='block';
  document.getElementById('element4').style.display ='block';
  document.getElementById('element5').style.display ='none';
  document.getElementById('subelement1').style.display ='none';
  document.getElementById('subelement2').style.display ='none';
  document.getElementById('subelement3').style.display ='none';
}
function trigger4(){
  document.getElementById('trigger1').style.display ='none';
  document.getElementById('trigger2').style.display ='none';
  document.getElementById('trigger3').style.display ='none';
  document.getElementById('element1').style.display ='none';
  document.getElementById('element2').style.display ='none';
  document.getElementById('element3').style.display ='none';
  document.getElementById('element4').style.display ='none';
  document.getElementById('element5').style.display ='none';
  document.getElementById('subelement1').style.display ='block';
  document.getElementById('subelement2').style.display ='block';
  document.getElementById('subelement3').style.display ='none';
}
function trigger5(){
  document.getElementById('trigger1').style.display ='none';
  document.getElementById('trigger2').style.display ='none';
  document.getElementById('trigger3').style.display ='none';
  document.getElementById('element1').style.display ='none';
  document.getElementById('element2').style.display ='none';
  document.getElementById('element3').style.display ='none';
  document.getElementById('element4').style.display ='none';
  document.getElementById('element5').style.display ='none';
  document.getElementById('subelement1').style.display ='none';
  document.getElementById('subelement2').style.display ='block';
  document.getElementById('subelement3').style.display ='block';
}
function trigger6(){
  document.getElementById('trigger1').style.display ='none';
  document.getElementById('trigger2').style.display ='none';
  document.getElementById('trigger3').style.display ='none';
  document.getElementById('element1').style.display ='none';
  document.getElementById('element2').style.display ='none';
  document.getElementById('element3').style.display ='none';
  document.getElementById('element4').style.display ='none';
  document.getElementById('element5').style.display ='none';
  document.getElementById('subelement1').style.display ='block';
  document.getElementById('subelement2').style.display ='block';
  document.getElementById('subelement3').style.display ='block';
}

function triggerBack(){
  document.getElementById('trigger1').style.display ='block';
  document.getElementById('trigger2').style.display ='block';
  document.getElementById('trigger3').style.display ='block';
  document.getElementById('element1').style.display ='none';
  document.getElementById('element2').style.display ='none';
  document.getElementById('element3').style.display ='none';
  document.getElementById('element4').style.display ='none';
  document.getElementById('element5').style.display ='none';
  document.getElementById('subelement1').style.display ='none';
  document.getElementById('subelement2').style.display ='none';
  document.getElementById('subelement3').style.display ='none';
}
```

```css
#trigger1 { display: block; background-color: red; }
#trigger2 { display: block; background-color: blue; }
#trigger3 { display: block; background-color: yellow; }

#element1 { display: none; background-color: purple; }
#element2 { display: none; background-color: green; }
#element3 { display: none; background-color: cyan; }
#element4 { display: none; background-color: violet; }
#element5 { display: none; background-color: magenta; }

#subelement1 { display: none; background-color: orange; }
#subelement2 { display: none; background-color: lightblue; }
#subelement3 { display: none; background-color: lightgreen; }

.container { width: 100%; }
.wrapper {
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.group {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}
.element {
    height: 50px;
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}
button {
    height: 20px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="group">
      <div class="element" id="trigger1" onClick="trigger1();"></div>
      <div class="element" id="trigger2" onClick="trigger2();"></div>
      <div class="element" id="trigger3" onClick="trigger3();"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
      <div class="element" id="element1" onClick="trigger4();"></div>
      <div class="element" id="element2" onClick="trigger5();"></div>
      <div class="element" id="element3" onClick="trigger6();"></div>
      <div class="element" id="element4"></div>
      <div class="element" id="element5"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
      <div class="element" id="subelement1"></div>
      <div class="element" id="subelement2"></div>
      <div class="element" id="subelement3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
      <button id="reset" onClick="triggerBack();">Back to start</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why the jQuery tag? I don't see any

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) this up would be to store the metadata on each element which governs which `.element` elements of which `.group` should be displayed. To do that you could use two data attributes, each containing the indexes of the group/elements to display.

As you've tagged the question with jQuery, try this:

```js
$('.element[data-element-index], #reset[data-element-index]').on('click', e => {  
  e.preventDefault();  
  $('.group, .element').hide();
  
  let $el = $(e.target);  
  let $group = $('.group').eq($el.data('group-index')).show();
  $group.find('.element').filter((i, el) => $el.data('element-index').indexOf($(el).index()) != -1).show();
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.group {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}

.group .trigger { display: block; }
#trigger1 { background-color: red; }
#trigger2 { background-color: blue; }
#trigger3 { background-color: yellow; }

.element {
  height: 50px;
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  display: none;
}
#element1 { background-color: purple; }
#element2 { background-color: green; }
#element3 { background-color: cyan; }
#element4 { background-color: violet; }
#element5 { background-color: magenta; }

#subelement1 { background-color: orange; }
#subelement2 { background-color: lightblue; }
#subelement3 { background-color: lightgreen; }

button {
  height: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="group">
      <div class="element trigger" id="trigger1" data-group-index="1" data-element-index="[0,1,2]"></div>
      <div class="element trigger" id="trigger2" data-group-index="1" data-element-index="[3,4]"></div>
      <div class="element trigger" id="trigger3" data-group-index="1" data-element-index="[0,2,3]"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
      <div class="element" id="element1" data-group-index="2" data-element-index="[0,1]"></div>
      <div class="element" id="element2" data-group-index="2" data-element-index="[1,2]"></div>
      <div class="element" id="element3" data-group-index="2" data-element-index="[0,1,2]"></div>
      <div class="element" id="element4"></div>
      <div class="element" id="element5"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
      <div class="element" id="subelement1"></div>
      <div class="element" id="subelement2"></div>
      <div class="element" id="subelement3"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button id="reset" data-group-index="0" data-element-index="[0,1,2]">Back to start</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also note that I tidied up the CSS slightly to DRY that up too.

Comment: The group index is set by the `data-group-index` attribute and the elements within that from the `data-element-index` array

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with classes.  Add a class to a top-level element based on what state it is.  All of the elements are hidden by default.  Just define in the CSS which elements are visible during each state.

```js
function trigger1(){
  document.getElementById('container').className = 'container state1';
}
function trigger2(){
  document.getElementById('container').className = 'container state2';
}
function trigger3(){
  document.getElementById('container').className = 'container state3';
}
function trigger4(){
  document.getElementById('container').className = 'container state4';
}
function trigger5(){
  document.getElementById('container').className = 'container state5';
}
function trigger6(){
  document.getElementById('container').className = 'container state6';
}

function triggerBack(){
  document.getElementById('container').className = 'container initial';
}
```

```css
#trigger1 { display: none; background-color: red; }
#trigger2 { display: none; background-color: blue; }
#trigger3 { display: none; background-color: yellow; }

#element1 { display: none; background-color: purple; }
#element2 { display: none; background-color: green; }
#element3 { display: none; background-color: cyan; }
#element4 { display: none; background-color: violet; }
#element5 { display: none; background-color: magenta; }

#subelement1 { display: none; background-color: orange; }
#subelement2 { display: none; background-color: lightblue; }
#subelement3 { display: none; background-color: lightgreen; }

.container { width: 100%; }
.wrapper {
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.group {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}
.element {
    height: 50px;
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}
button {
    height: 20px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}


.state1 #element1,
.state1 #element2,
.state1 #element3 {
  display: block;
}

.state2 #element4,
.state2 #element5 {
  display: block;
}

.state3 #element1,
.state3 #element3,
.state3 #element4 {
  display: block;
}

.state4 #subelement1,
.state4 #subelement2 {
  display: block;
}

.state5 #subelement2,
.state5 #subelement3 {
  display: block;
}

.state6 #subelement1,
.state6 #subelement2,
.state6 #subelement3 {
  display: block;
}

.initial #trigger1,
.initial #trigger2,
.initial #trigger3 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="container initial">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="group">
      <div class="element" id="trigger1" onClick="trigger1();"></div>
      <div class="element" id="trigger2" onClick="trigger2();"></div>
      <div class="element" id="trigger3" onClick="trigger3();"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
      <div class="element" id="element1" onClick="trigger4();"></div>
      <div class="element" id="element2" onClick="trigger5();"></div>
      <div class="element" id="element3" onClick="trigger6();"></div>
      <div class="element" id="element4"></div>
      <div class="element" id="element5"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
      <div class="element" id="subelement1"></div>
      <div class="element" id="subelement2"></div>
      <div class="element" id="subelement3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
      <button id="reset" onClick="triggerBack();">Back to start</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, if you still need to do this with javascript, you could do something similar to this:

```
function hide(ids){
  ids.forEach(id => {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display ='none';
  });
}

function show(ids){
  ids.forEach(id => {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display ='block';
  });
}

function trigger1(){
  hide([
    'trigger1',
    'trigger2',
    'trigger3',
    'element4',
    'element5',
    'subelement1',
    'subelement2',
    'subelement3'
  ]);
  show([
    'element1',
    'element2',
    'element3'
  ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try using jQuery and hide the elements by class, so you don't have to hide everything by id or do you strictly have to use vanillaJS?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $(".stuff").hide();
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>This is a heading</h2>

<p class="stuff">This is a paragraph.</p>
<p class="stuff">This is another paragraph.</p>
<p>this is a different paragraph, that won't be hidden on click</p>

<button>Click me to hide paragraphs</button>

</body>
</html>
```